# How can I save historical data in a data warehouse system only if it has been modified?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, data-warehouse

I want to populate a SQLServer table to be used in a data warehouse system. This table is called DimStudent. This data comes from a postgreSQL source database and is updated every day to have new students loaded. To fill this dimension table I use the visual studio component, slow variation dimension. What I want to know is how to save the historical records only if I change the value of a field in the source, since when I run the task it loads all the rows and leaves the previous ones (already loaded) as historical.

This is the current load:

[image]

This is de load that i want (only if "marital status" change"):

[image]

Here the marital status is configured as a historical attribute using date start and date end:
[image]

Comment: I've tried this and it works as expected i.e. a new record is only created if the data changes. Are there any other columns set to 'historical attribute'? Are you sure that the values for Marital Status are identical in source and target e.g. non-printing characters, leading/trailing spaces etc.?

Comment: maybe there is an option to save only when the value change , but i don't saw nothing about this. In this case 'marital status' is the only historical attribute because is a test and  the value from the field not change because execute 2 times in a row